# Shorten the table names

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am using SQL Server and wondering if it's possible to shorten the table names. For example, my current SQL syntax is:

```
SELECT 
    t.Titlename
FROM [dbo].[Order] o 
JOIN [dbo].[Title] t ON o.titleid=t.TitleId
```

However, if I just try doing `select titlename from order` I get an error. Why is this so? What would be the 'shortest' tablename I could reference; and why is it requiring the `[dbo]` namespace?

Comment: It would be helpful to know the exact error message.  But I suspect you're doing a join of "order" and "title" ... and the column "titlename" is in the table you're NOT selecting: title.  Whoops :)

Comment: what do you mean by `'shortest' tablename` ?

Comment: @Squirrel - the OP probably means "Do I need "dbo" and the brackets?"  The answer, of course, is "No" :)  Not unless you need to specify the schema (here, schema == "dbo").  PS: It's called a "schema", NOT a "namespace".

Comment: @Squirrel yea I mean without explicitly declaring a namespace `dbo.` and without having to do the bracket escaping `[...]`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't *require* the `[dbo]` namespace, assuming that is the currently selected database. But it *does* require the `Title` table to be joined to `Order` to get the `Titlename` column:

```
SELECT 
    t.Titlename
FROM [Order] o 
JOIN Title t ON o.titleid=t.TitleId
```

[Demo on SQLFiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!18/aba26d/2)

Note that `Order` *must* be enclosed in `[]` because it is an SQL reserved keyword.

It's also worth noting the point that is made in the article @GregLow mentions, which indicates that queries cannot be reused if object name resolution needs to occur. So it would generally be *preferred* to write the query as you originally did.

Comment: If it's SQL Server, you should almost always use 2 part names in code.

Comment: I haven't upvoted any answer. I didn't say "must", I said "should". My point is that the OP should be encouraged to use two part names, even if you can (in some circumstances) get away with single part names. It's not building reliable code. Using single part object names in SQL Server is poor practice.

Comment: Here's an MSDN whitepaper that I wrote that includes the topic: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/sql/sql-server-2012/dn148262(v=msdn.10)  I rarely downvote anything.

Comment: That's a long article. Care to point me to the relevant page(s)?

Comment: Yep, it's an in-depth topic. The section on "Object Name Resolution" would be a good start.

Comment: But I didn't downvote (or not intentionally). Does anything on the page say that? I have no idea what you're talking about.

Answer (score 2):

If your currently selected database be `dbo`, then it *shouldn't* be necessary to use the fully qualified object name.  However, you have another problem, because `ORDER` is a reserved SQL Server keyword.  The following should work:

```
SELECT t.Titlename
FROM [Order] o 
INNER JOIN [Title] t
    ON o.titleid = t.TitleId;
```

Here, using `[Order]` instead of `Order` counts as escaping that table name.

Comment: I see. is doing `[term]` in SQL server similar to doing the backticks `\`term\`` in mysql?

Comment: @David542 Yes.  On SQL Server, double quotes `"Order"` might also work.  Double quotes is the ANSI way of escaping object names.

Comment: got it, thanks. Is `[` and `]` SQL server specific? Or is that common in other DBMS's as well?

Comment: @David542 MS Access also uses bracket syntax.  Not sure on other RDBDS.  Double quotes, should, in theory, work on any database though.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen double quotes won't work on MySQL unless ANSI_QUOTES mode is enabled.